# Best way to have hover and selection state/effects of a geometry in three.js?

Tags: three.js, post-processing

I'm working on a three.js application which allows user to interact with the geometry by clicking, dragging and hovering etc...

The app need to have hover and selections state of the geometry to indicate and differentiate between selected, hovered and normal geometry. So I have used the 2 outlinePass effects for each of the state based on mousemove and click event.

- hover uses outlinePass **WITHOUT** any `patternTexture`
- click event uses a outlinePass with a `patternTexture`

But the [following post](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-outline-pass-individual-geometry-rather-than-whole-scene/3269/6) mentions that using 2 outlinePasses is not recommended.

So I'm wondering what's the best approach for this requirement